# Conditional counter cache dependent on Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, counter-cache

I have a [counter_culture](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture) counter that depends on whether a [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) attachment is defined or not:

```
class Post < ::ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  counter_culture :user, column_name: Proc.new { |p| p.media? ? 'posts_with_photo_count' : nil }
end
```

The issue is that the counter is not updated when the post is either *updated* nor *destroyed*.

I guess it should have something to do with *Paperclip*'s own callback system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guessed what is happening. It's in fact due to a flow mismatch regarding the callbacks of both *counter_culture* and *Paperclip*.

Since on `after_update`, the attachment is not already processed when the counter condition executes, `p.media?` returns false and the counter is not incremented.

A similar thing happens on `after_destroy`, since the attachment is destroyed on `before_destroy`.

I came up with the following solution for this issue:

```
counter_culture :user, column_name: Proc.new { |p| (p.photo_file_name? || !p.photo_file_name_was.nil?)  ? 'posts_with_photo_count' : nil }
```

It basically considers the `_file_name` for creates and updates and verifies if the attachment was cleared on destroy.